# Translating and renaming filename (without its extension) in Python

Tags: python

I need to translate (from Cyrillic to Latin ) filenames (without extensions) in a folder.

I have separated names and extensions, however I'm getting a FileNotFoundError while using **os.rename()** function.
What is the best solution for that?

Here is my code:

import os
import shutil

def normalize(path):

```
CYRILLIC = ('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч','Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я')

LATIN = ('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Zh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'Ts', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', '', 'Y',' ', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya')

TRANSLIT_DICT = {}


for c, l in zip(CYRILLIC, LATIN):

    TRANSLIT_DICT[ord(c)] = l

    TRANSLIT_DICT[ord(c.lower())] = l.lower()




for item in os.listdir():

    if not os.path.isdir(item):
        
        file_name = os.path.basename(item)

        filename_without_ext = file_name[:file_name.rindex('.')]

        os.rename(filename_without_ext, filename_without_ext.translate(TRANSLIT_DICT))
```

Comment: It's usually hard to give advice without seeing your actual code. With what you have said here, all I can say is the file wasn't found. Did you type the filename wrong? Try `os.listdir()`. Do you see that filename?

Comment: print the value of variables to see why the function failed, or use a debugger

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have shared the code.

Comment: I suspect the file is not found because you're not giving `os.rename()` the filename; you're removing the extension, which is part of the filename. You should add that back first, to both `src` and `dst`, assuming you want the new filename to have the same extension.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joe for the hint!

           name = os.path.splitext(item)[0]

            ext = os.path.splitext(item)[1]

            os.rename(item, name.translate(TRANSLIT_DICT) + ext)

Now it works!